# Issue on Gitolite permissions on a derived branch from a restricted one

Tags: git, permissions, branch, gitolite

I have two branches `dev` and `ui`, and I'm trying to merge ui into dev on a temporary branch `dev-ui`. I've created a new branch from dev, and merged ui into it. So my branch schema is:

```
dev ----- dev-ui
ui  --/
```

I'm using Gitolite, and I've locked `master` and `dev` branches from unauthorized writes. This is my config related file:

```
@myRepoDevs = dev1 dev2

repo    myRepo
  RW+                            = admin
  R     dev master               = @myRepoDevs
  -     dev master               = @myRepoDevs
  RW                             = @myRepoDevs
```

When one of two devs tries to push on `dev-ui` to `origin`, he receives this error from git console:

```
remote: FATAL: W refs/heads/dev-ui myRepo dev1 DENIED by refs/heads/dev
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/dev-ui
To myServer:myRepo
 ! [remote rejected] dev-ui -> dev-ui (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'myServer:myRepo'
```

Why he can't push on `dev-ui`?
Is because it is directly derived from `dev`, or is because it has the prefix `dev` on its name? Or an other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitolite uses [**refex**](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#refex):

> A refex is a word I made up to mean "a regex that matches a ref".
>
> A refex is implicitly anchored at the start, but not at the end. In regular expression lingo, a `^` is assumed at the start (but no `$` at the end is assumed).
> So a refex of `master` will match all these refs:

```
refs/heads/master
refs/heads/master1
refs/heads/master2
refs/heads/master/full
```

Son in your case, you need `dev$` in your gitolite rules.